# PHP/SQL repeat cycle until data is unique in PHP or create SQL queries ad hoc

Tags: php, codeigniter, controls, key, unique

I need to generate key codes for users so i need that to be unique in db.

I need to repeat this cycle until key is unique:

```
create key;

if($key is not in db){

  insert key;

}else{

repeat control with new key;

}
```

i thought about while() but can't understand how to implement that.

Other method to insert db unique keys and update db unique key could be written in sql queries directly instead of using php script? (INSERT/UPDATE UNIQUE KEYS with Sql Query)

hoping is clear the question.

Comment: The DB normally takes care of that standard job. It looks like you want to solve that with PHP which is not the best tool for the job.

Comment: well how can i insert & update a random alphanumeric hash unique directly in Mysql? will be better sure! if you can show me code i can edit my question

Comment: Now as you have better clarified your requirements, I'm pretty sure that this has been asked and even answered before. Please feel free to search the site. Don't look for codeigniter in your search, just concentrate on the specific database server you're using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$key = create_unique_key();

while( this_key_exists($key) )
{
 $key = create_unique_key();
}
//If you got here - the value of $key is unique and doesn't exist in db
```

Explanation:
You first create a unique key using the custom function `create_uniuqe_key`, so now
we have a starting value for `$key`.
Second , we have a `while` loop , please remember:

> while( expr )

as long the expression return true we will get into the loop.
So , as long as our custom function `this_key_exists` (which return true or false) returns true (which means - the key is not that uniuqe - exists in the database) we will create a new unique key and check it again and again.

Comment: best not dangerous approach i think

Comment: I believe so also , notify me if not. Good luck :)

Answer (score 2):

Try just using [UUID](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid)

or add a unique constraint on the column in the database and keep trying to insert the row until there's no mysql error

```
do {
    //insert using uniqid() or some random string
} while( $check_for_mysql_error );
```

Comment: what the log errors files will become if i will have 1milion users??

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Creates a unique URL for a page language by adding a 'dash number'
 * at the end of the provided user URL
 * @param string $page The current page
 * @param string $url The URL to make unique
 * @param type $lang The language to make unique for (you can have the same URL for same page in diffrent languages)
 * @return string The new URL
 */
function uniquePageUrl($page, $url, $lang){
    while(TRUE){
        $result = $this->db->from('pages')->where('page <>', $page)->where('lang',$lang)->where('url',$url)->limit(1)->get()->row();
        if($result) //we already have a page URL for this language like the one we try to use
            $url = increment_string($url,'-');
        else
            return $url;
    }
}
```

Comment: mmm i like the while(TRUE){} does it will charge the pcu??

Comment: If your code is written properly, it will return after three loops at most.

Comment: `while(TRUE){` ? it will always return `true` which will cause the loop to run until infinty , no?

Comment: Indeed. The catch is that **the code runs into a function**, and it will **return the first unique URL** that it finds and then it **will stop executing**. It will run through several loops (three at most, usually). The idea is that I have tested the code (I use it in several of my projects)

Comment: sure it will return an infite loop cause IT IS AN INFINITE LOOP i think it's too dangerous :P

Comment: It will return a value, not an infinite loop. All the code examples that will do what you want, will run on the same principle: "do something until a unique value is found". And that's exactly what my sample does. Your accepted answer does exactly the same, but by spreading the code over two functions, instead of only one (you can easily add a loop stopper after a certain number of loops if you are too fearful)